Java JAX-WS SSL keystore reset
I have a peculiar problem while contacting a webservice over SSL. I am running my application on a Apache Tomcat instance;
I have several SSL certificates to cuse on different remote servers.
When I connect the first time ( ServerA) all works fine, I use
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", CaCertsFileName );
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");    
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "jks");    
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/Pahttofile/FilePFX1.pfx");
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "XXXX");`

When I connect to other ws ( ServerB,  other remote server) and change properties to use other SSL certifacate, the conversations use the first certificate
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", CaCertsFileName );
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");    
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "jks");    
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/Pahttofile/FilePFX2.pfx");
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "YYYY");`

If I reset JVM and start again and I test First Server B the connections works fine, but the Server A connections also doesn't work.
Could anybody know how I can reset SSL certificates using java language.

The system properties are used only when the default SSLContext is created, which is the first time it is referenced in a given JVM process. Replacing the default for one or more connection(s) depends on how you do the connection(s) which you don't show. But IF your client certs are from different issuers AND the servers specify 'requested' CA(s) in CertificateRequest, which most but not all do, you can put both client certs/keys (and their chains) in one keystore and use it for all connections -- JSSE will automatically choose the correct cert/key based on the CA(s) specified by the server.

thanks, I test put client certs in a one keystore, but doesnt work. I get works fine on apache tomcat under netbeans, but when I deploy on websphere only works the first connections
